# How to optimize this MySQL query with an index

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT product_id, product_amount,count(product_amount) as order_status
 FROM order_history 
 GROUP BY product_amount, product_id ;
```

How can I index the table? Anybody please help.

Comment: This query is not proper as you are taking COUNT(product_amount) which will return just one row and other records will return multiple rows.

Comment: Also on your `SELECT` clause, you have `AS order status` which should have no spaces or enclose in quotations.

Comment: @ChristianMark changed query.How can I index the table?

Comment: How is it possible that the count of a product amount indicates the order status?

Comment: I don't really understand the reason why you have to SELECT `product_amount` with count for the same field. Can you state what you want to achieve here? Please give your schema, sample data and sample output.

Answer (score 0):

`product_id` would be your Primary Key so it should already be indexed.

Comment: product_id is not my the primary key

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add product_id as index, here's the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `order_history` ADD INDEX `product_id` (`product_id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `product_id` as index and `product_id` could not be duplicate then you use this query

```
ALTER TABLE `order_history` ADD UNIQUE INDEX ( `product_id` )
```

If you want to add `product_id` as index and `product_id` could be duplicate then you use this query

```
ALTER TABLE `order_history` ADD INDEX ( `product_id` )
```